No entiendo cómo puedo desarrollar este problema de python y seaborn aplicado a dataframes
En el ejercicio me dicen que puedo hacerlo de dos formas: un gráfico para la evolución por trimestre de los confirmados por provincia de España y otro para la evolución por trimestre de los recuperados por provincia de España o juntarlos en un mismo gráfico para la evolución por trimestre y provincia de España.
He intentado hacerlo por separado pero no me sale ninguna de las dos formas, me gustaría si se pudieran mostrar las dos.
En el eje "X" he puesto los meses (Enero, febrero y marzo) para ver la evolución trimestral que me piden. En el eje "Y" me gustaría poner el número de confirmados, recuperados o ambos (si escogemos la opción de plasmarlo en un único gráfico) y en el argumento "hue" la lista de provincias para que de un color a cada una.
Tengo tres documentos csv (datos para cada mes):
FIPS,Admin2,Province_State,Country_Region,Last_Update,Lat,Long_,Confirmed,Deaths,Recovered,Active,Combined_Key,Incident_Rate,Case_Fatality_Ratio
,,Andalusia,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,37.5443,-4.7278,264371,5123,10671,248577,"Andalusia, Spain",3137.039219071589,1.937807096844964
,,Aragon,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,41.5976,-0.9057,80023,2634,3772,73617,"Aragon, Spain",6059.658363786984,3.291553678317484
,,Asturias,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,43.3614,-5.8593,27171,1343,1063,24765,"Asturias, Spain",2658.0773915212703,4.94276986492952
,,Baleares,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,39.710358,2.995148,35569,469,1533,33567,"Baleares, Spain",2993.469222871185,1.3185639180184991
,,C. Valenciana,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,39.484,-0.7533,148797,2941,9970,135886,"C. Valenciana, Spain",2990.913109207313,1.9765183437838127
,,Canarias,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,28.2916,-16.6291,26859,415,1537,24907,"Canarias, Spain",1217.0459843916874,1.5451059235265647
,,Cantabria,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,43.1828,-3.9878,17948,393,2287,15268,"Cantabria, Spain",3085.7522079770856,2.1896590149320256
,,Castilla - La Mancha,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,39.2796,-3.0977,100673,4086,6392,90195,"Castilla - La Mancha, Spain",4947.375197616368,4.058685049616083
,,Castilla y Leon,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,41.8357,-4.3976,132611,5081,8716,118814,"Castilla y Leon, Spain",5507.7120262088865,3.8315071902029243
,,Catalonia,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,41.5912,1.5209,356724,8723,26203,321798,"Catalonia, Spain",4714.5609336819425,2.445307857054754
,,Ceuta,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,35.8894,-5.3213,3072,59,163,2850,"Ceuta, Spain",3621.403057916514,1.9205729166666667
,,Extremadura,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,39.4937,-6.0679,37208,1067,2652,33489,"Extremadura, Spain",3492.3185511120455,2.867662868200387
,,Galicia,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,42.5751,-8.1339,61143,1379,9204,50560,"Galicia, Spain",2264.1857385515923,2.2553685622229853
,,La Rioja,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,42.2871,-2.5396,18426,586,3107,14733,"La Rioja, Spain",5876.181151956016,3.180288722457397
,,Madrid,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,40.4168,-3.7038,399499,11828,40736,346935,"Madrid, Spain",6015.0574051715175,2.9607082871296297
,,Melilla,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,35.2923,-2.9381,4540,43,125,4372,"Melilla, Spain",5360.790657582449,0.947136563876652
,,Murcia,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,37.9922,-1.1307,60316,744,2180,57392,"Murcia, Spain",4054.412860977251,1.2335035479806353
,,Navarra,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,42.6954,-1.6761,42494,960,3905,37629,"Navarra, Spain",6538.081625242712,2.259142467171836
,,Pais Vasco,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,42.9896,-2.6189,110821,2963,16160,91698,"Pais Vasco, Spain",5088.480540709314,2.673680981041499
,,Unknown,Spain,2021-01-02 05:22:33,,,0,0,0,0,"Unknown, Spain",,


FIPS,Admin2,Province_State,Country_Region,Last_Update,Lat,Long_,Confirmed,Deaths,Recovered,Active,Combined_Key,Incident_Rate,Case_Fatality_Ratio
,,Andalusia,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,37.5443,-4.7278,264371,5123,10671,248577,"Andalusia, Spain",3137.039219071589,1.937807096844964
,,Aragon,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,41.5976,-0.9057,80023,2634,3772,73617,"Aragon, Spain",6059.658363786984,3.291553678317484
,,Asturias,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,43.3614,-5.8593,27171,1343,1063,24765,"Asturias, Spain",2658.0773915212703,4.94276986492952
,,Baleares,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,39.710358,2.995148,35569,469,1533,33567,"Baleares, Spain",2993.469222871185,1.3185639180184991
,,C. Valenciana,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,39.484,-0.7533,148797,2941,9970,135886,"C. Valenciana, Spain",2990.913109207313,1.9765183437838127
,,Canarias,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,28.2916,-16.6291,26859,415,1537,24907,"Canarias, Spain",1217.0459843916874,1.5451059235265647
,,Cantabria,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,43.1828,-3.9878,17948,393,2287,15268,"Cantabria, Spain",3085.7522079770856,2.1896590149320256
,,Castilla - La Mancha,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,39.2796,-3.0977,100673,4086,6392,90195,"Castilla - La Mancha, Spain",4947.375197616368,4.058685049616083
,,Castilla y Leon,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,41.8357,-4.3976,132611,5081,8716,118814,"Castilla y Leon, Spain",5507.7120262088865,3.8315071902029243
,,Catalonia,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,41.5912,1.5209,356724,8723,26203,321798,"Catalonia, Spain",4714.5609336819425,2.445307857054754
,,Ceuta,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,35.8894,-5.3213,3072,59,163,2850,"Ceuta, Spain",3621.403057916514,1.9205729166666667
,,Extremadura,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,39.4937,-6.0679,37208,1067,2652,33489,"Extremadura, Spain",3492.3185511120455,2.867662868200387
,,Galicia,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,42.5751,-8.1339,61143,1379,9204,50560,"Galicia, Spain",2264.1857385515923,2.2553685622229853
,,La Rioja,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,42.2871,-2.5396,18426,586,3107,14733,"La Rioja, Spain",5876.181151956016,3.180288722457397
,,Madrid,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,40.4168,-3.7038,399499,11828,40736,346935,"Madrid, Spain",6015.0574051715175,2.9607082871296297
,,Melilla,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,35.2923,-2.9381,4540,43,125,4372,"Melilla, Spain",5360.790657582449,0.947136563876652
,,Murcia,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,37.9922,-1.1307,60316,744,2180,57392,"Murcia, Spain",4054.412860977251,1.2335035479806353
,,Navarra,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,42.6954,-1.6761,42494,960,3905,37629,"Navarra, Spain",6538.081625242712,2.259142467171836
,,Pais Vasco,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,42.9896,-2.6189,110821,2963,16160,91698,"Pais Vasco, Spain",5088.480540709314,2.673680981041499
,,Unknown,Spain,2021-01-03 05:22:52,,,0,0,0,0,"Unknown, Spain",,


FIPS,Admin2,Province_State,Country_Region,Last_Update,Lat,Long_,Confirmed,Deaths,Recovered,Active,Combined_Key,Incident_Rate,Case_Fatality_Ratio
,,Andalusia,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,37.5443,-4.7278,264371,5123,10671,248577,"Andalusia, Spain",3137.039219071589,1.937807096844964
,,Aragon,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,41.5976,-0.9057,80023,2634,3772,73617,"Aragon, Spain",6059.658363786984,3.291553678317484
,,Asturias,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,43.3614,-5.8593,27171,1343,1063,24765,"Asturias, Spain",2658.0773915212703,4.94276986492952
,,Baleares,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,39.710358,2.995148,35569,469,1533,33567,"Baleares, Spain",2993.469222871185,1.3185639180184991
,,C. Valenciana,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,39.484,-0.7533,148797,2941,9970,135886,"C. Valenciana, Spain",2990.913109207313,1.9765183437838127
,,Canarias,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,28.2916,-16.6291,26859,415,1537,24907,"Canarias, Spain",1217.0459843916874,1.5451059235265647
,,Cantabria,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,43.1828,-3.9878,17948,393,2287,15268,"Cantabria, Spain",3085.7522079770856,2.1896590149320256
,,Castilla - La Mancha,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,39.2796,-3.0977,100673,4086,6392,90195,"Castilla - La Mancha, Spain",4947.375197616368,4.058685049616083
,,Castilla y Leon,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,41.8357,-4.3976,132611,5081,8716,118814,"Castilla y Leon, Spain",5507.7120262088865,3.8315071902029243
,,Catalonia,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,41.5912,1.5209,356724,8723,26203,321798,"Catalonia, Spain",4714.5609336819425,2.445307857054754
,,Ceuta,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,35.8894,-5.3213,3072,59,163,2850,"Ceuta, Spain",3621.403057916514,1.9205729166666667
,,Extremadura,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,39.4937,-6.0679,37208,1067,2652,33489,"Extremadura, Spain",3492.3185511120455,2.867662868200387
,,Galicia,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,42.5751,-8.1339,61143,1379,9204,50560,"Galicia, Spain",2264.1857385515923,2.2553685622229853
,,La Rioja,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,42.2871,-2.5396,18426,586,3107,14733,"La Rioja, Spain",5876.181151956016,3.180288722457397
,,Madrid,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,40.4168,-3.7038,399499,11828,40736,346935,"Madrid, Spain",6015.0574051715175,2.9607082871296297
,,Melilla,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,35.2923,-2.9381,4540,43,125,4372,"Melilla, Spain",5360.790657582449,0.947136563876652
,,Murcia,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,37.9922,-1.1307,60316,744,2180,57392,"Murcia, Spain",4054.412860977251,1.2335035479806353
,,Navarra,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,42.6954,-1.6761,42494,960,3905,37629,"Navarra, Spain",6538.081625242712,2.259142467171836
,,Pais Vasco,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,42.9896,-2.6189,110821,2963,16160,91698,"Pais Vasco, Spain",5088.480540709314,2.673680981041499
,,Unknown,Spain,2021-01-04 05:22:02,,,0,0,0,0,"Unknown, Spain",,


El siguiente código es lo que he ido intentando pero no sé cómo avanzar por más que le doy vueltas:
df_1 = pd.read_csv("/Users/Alvaro/Desktop/Ejercicios Master Big Data y business intelligence/Documentos tema python/Trabajo final parte 2/COVID_01-01-2021.csv", sep = ",")
df_2 = pd.read_csv("/Users/Alvaro/Desktop/Ejercicios Master Big Data y business intelligence/Documentos tema python/Trabajo final parte 2/COVID_01-02-2021.csv", sep = ",")
df_3 = pd.read_csv("/Users/Alvaro/Desktop/Ejercicios Master Big Data y business intelligence/Documentos tema python/Trabajo final parte 2/COVID_01-03-2021.csv", sep = ",")

df_total = pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3])

df_total_fil = df_total.loc [df_total ["Country_Region"] == "Spain", ["Province_State", "Confirmed", "Recovered", "Last_Update" ]]
print(df_total_fil.shape)
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
df_total_fil = df_total_fil.replace (to_replace = "Unknown", value = np.nan)
df_total_fil.dropna (inplace = True )
print(df_total_fil.shape)
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print (df_total_fil)

sns.lineplot (x = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo"], y = ["Confirmed"], data = df_total_fil, hue = ["Country_Region" == "Spain"]).set_title("Casos confirmados de coronavirus por primer trimestre 2021")
plt.show()

Espero haberme expresado bien y adjuntado todo correctamente. Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Hola Alvaro, ¿la idea seria tener los tres mese en el eje x,  el nº de casos y una linea por comunidad (19)? Una observacion, creo que tus tres dataframes no difieren en los datos, solo la fecha cambia, todas las graficas serian planas... No se si es correcto o es algun error en los datos

hola @FJSevilla , tienes toda la razón, no me había fijado ya que en el resto de países sí que cambian los datos. Voy a comprobar si está todo correcto y actualizo los datos sino. Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Buenas de nuevo @FJSevilla , me han confirmado que está correcto que los datos sean los mismos, que no es tanto el resultado final sino la filtración de datos y representación. Un saludo y muchas gracias!!

El error se debe a que le estás pasando al argumento x la lista ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo"], pero para empezar ninguna de esas columnas existen en el dataframe.
Si quieres un gráfico de líneas, en la que cada una sea una CCAA, en el eje X estén los meses y en el Y el conteo de casos, se me ocurre que pueses hacer algo así:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


df_1 = pd.read_csv("COVID_01-01-2021.csv", sep = ",")
df_2 = pd.read_csv("COVID_01-01-2021.csv", sep = ",")
df_3 = pd.read_csv("COVID_01-01-2021.csv", sep = ",")

df_total = (
    pd.concat(
        (df_1, df_2, df_3),
        keys=("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo"),
        names=["Mes"])
    .droplevel(1)
    .query(
        "Country_Region == 'Spain' & Province_State != 'Unknown'"
    )
    [["Province_State", "Confirmed", "Recovered"]]
)

ax = sns.lineplot(
    x="Mes",
    y="Confirmed",
    data=df_total,
    hue="Province_State",
    legend="full"
)
ax.set_title("Casos confirmados de coronavirus por primer trimestre 2021")
sns.move_legend(ax, "upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Lo más relevante es que al usar concat hacemos uso del argumento keys para crear un nuevo nivel en el índice que identifique el mes. Quedando nuestros dataframes concatenados asi:

>>> df_total

               Province_State  Confirmed  Recovered
Mes                                                
Enero               Andalusia     264371      10671
Enero                  Aragon      80023       3772
Enero                Asturias      27171       1063
Enero                Baleares      35569       1533
Enero           C. Valenciana     148797       9970
Enero                Canarias      26859       1537
Enero               Cantabria      17948       2287
Enero    Castilla - La Mancha     100673       6392
Enero         Castilla y Leon     132611       8716
Enero               Catalonia     356724      26203
Enero                   Ceuta       3072        163
Enero             Extremadura      37208       2652
Enero                 Galicia      61143       9204
Enero                La Rioja      18426       3107
Enero                  Madrid     399499      40736
Enero                 Melilla       4540        125
Enero                  Murcia      60316       2180
Enero                 Navarra      42494       3905
Enero              Pais Vasco     110821      16160
Febrero             Andalusia     264371      10671
Febrero                Aragon      80023       3772
Febrero              Asturias      27171       1063
Febrero              Baleares      35569       1533
Febrero         C. Valenciana     148797       9970
Febrero              Canarias      26859       1537
Febrero             Cantabria      17948       2287
Febrero  Castilla - La Mancha     100673       6392
Febrero       Castilla y Leon     132611       8716
Febrero             Catalonia     356724      26203
Febrero                 Ceuta       3072        163
Febrero           Extremadura      37208       2652
Febrero               Galicia      61143       9204
Febrero              La Rioja      18426       3107
Febrero                Madrid     399499      40736
Febrero               Melilla       4540        125
Febrero                Murcia      60316       2180
Febrero               Navarra      42494       3905
Febrero            Pais Vasco     110821      16160
Marzo               Andalusia     264371      10671
Marzo                  Aragon      80023       3772
Marzo                Asturias      27171       1063
Marzo                Baleares      35569       1533
Marzo           C. Valenciana     148797       9970
Marzo                Canarias      26859       1537
Marzo               Cantabria      17948       2287
Marzo    Castilla - La Mancha     100673       6392
Marzo         Castilla y Leon     132611       8716
Marzo               Catalonia     356724      26203
Marzo                   Ceuta       3072        163
Marzo             Extremadura      37208       2652
Marzo                 Galicia      61143       9204
Marzo                La Rioja      18426       3107
Marzo                  Madrid     399499      40736
Marzo                 Melilla       4540        125
Marzo                  Murcia      60316       2180
Marzo                 Navarra      42494       3905
Marzo              Pais Vasco     110821      16160


Teniendo eso ya podemos decirle a seborn.lineplot() que use el índice/columna "Mes" para el eje x.
El resultado es algo así:

Quizás usar este tipo de gráfico aquí no sea la forma más legible de mostrar los datos ya que 19 lineas son muchas lineas que diferenciar y seguir, pero eso es otro tema. Lo que si se podria hacer es mejorar la paleta y cambiar el estilo de las lineas para que sea más fácil distinguiralas unas de otras.

Muchísimas gracias @FJSevilla, entiendo perfectamente lo que me comentas y creo que sí, como dices, no tiene mucho sentido representarlo al final así. Creo que me he explicado mal, ya que como decía era un punto en cada mes para el valor de la provincia y que esos tres puntos los uniera una línea. No sé si queda claro a lo que me refiero. Comentamos. Un saludo y muchas gracias!!

Pero si no estoy malinterpretando algo el gráfico seria el mismo, solo que necesitas agregar la marcas de los datos, por ejemplo, puedes hacerlo simplemente pasándole el argumento  marker='o' a sns.lineplot.

era eso exactamente. Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda y la explicación. Siempre es un placer. Un saludo!
